# Why does my badges page have fewer badges than my usercard says I have?

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

If you check [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3024277/me123) you will see there's a problem with my badges.

There where it shows the Gravatar and reputation, it says I have 15 badges. But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3024277/me123?tab=badges) where it shows what badges I have it only says I have 14. How many do I really have? Why does it show two different counts?

Comment: You have 14 different badges and custodian badge twice.

Comment: Why a downvote, I was just asking?

Comment: Don't take downvotes on Meta personally or seriously, this question might seem "too simple" that's all. (not my own opinion)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two different counts here: you have 14 *unique* badges and 15 bronze badges in *total*. You earned the Custodian badge twice.

Note that if you start earning silver or gold badges, their counts will be displayed separately under your gravatar.

Take a look at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) for a larger contrast, making it easier to see the difference; I have (20 gold + 239 silver + 389 bronze
=) 648 badges in total, but only 149 *unique* badges.